# Where to put http get function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I understand that everything dealing with database should be put inside a model class. But what about the data I get from a HTTP GET resource, like say a xml file, csv file or something like that. Should I make a helper for it? a library? or is it good in a model?

Regards

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a file from a GET resource? Do you mean a file name or path?

Comment: Like accessing a url like http://example.com/files/getfile.xml, using cURL may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models should be used for anything involving data retrieval or storage, that includes calling webservices, queries, loading and parsing xml.

Then again this is just a suggestion, you could leave it all in your controller or use a library and it would make no difference other than that you're not conforming to MVC principles.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you are going to store the data from the GET resource in the database then using a model to process the data is definitely the way to go.